# How to pass variable between components in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have two components, Navbar and ShoppingList. When the user is logged in so I get response from api, I set isLoggedIn variable to true. What I want to do is to show "Logout" button on my navbar when the user is logged in and hide it where he is not. How to pass this value to Navbar component?

ShoppingList fragment

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axiosInstance from '../apis/apiURLS';

function ShoppingList() {

  export const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  
  const getShoppingList = async () => {
    await axiosInstance.get('/shoppinglist/')
    .then(response => {
    if(response){
    setIsLoggedIn(true)
    setShoppingList(response.data)
    }
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getShoppingList();
  }, [])
```

Navbar fragment

```
        <div className='navbar'>
            <div className='menu-bar-logout' onClick={handleLogout}>
            <div class="icon">
            </div>
            <span>Logout</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you share more code implementation on your `ShoppingList` and `Navbar` component. We cannot decide without component hierarchy to check which method is best to passing data between components.

Comment: if your component `ShoppingList` is loading `Navbar` then simply `<Navbar isLoggedin={isLoggedIn} />` but if its loaded before or somewhere else then u cant UNLESS you use context or some global store like redux. Also, in general, why `ShoppingList` is responsible for logging in a user? Single responsobility principle - a single class, or file, should be responsible for a single thing. `ShoppingList` sounds like rendering a shoping list not logging in a user or to do anything with a user. if u need a user if he is logged in in `ShoppingList` then fetch from ur global store or context